# how to ignore soap stuff on deserializing xml to object?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

When I get a xml, I need to deserialize it to a specific object and pass it via parameter in a web service method.

Code:

```
 var document = new XmlDocument();
 document.Load(@"C:\Desktop\CteWebservice.xml");
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OCTE));
 var octe = (OCTE) serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(document.OuterXml));

 serviceClient.InsertOCTE(octe);
```

But when I try to deserialize I get a error saying

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" > was not expected.
```

I need to ignore the envelope tag and other SOAP stuff.
How can I do that?

The xml file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
              xmlns:ns="http://192.168.1.180:8085/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:INCLUIRCONHECIMENTOFRETESAIDA>
     <ns:CONHECIMENTOFRETE>
        <ns:CSTICMS></ns:CSTICMS>
     </ns:CONHECIMENTOFRETE>
  </ns:INCLUIRCONHECIMENTOFRETESAIDA>
<soapenv:Body>
```

Test Code:

```
XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace m = "http://192.168.1.180:8085/"; 
var soapBody = xdoc.Descendants(soap + "Body").First().FirstNode;

var serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(OCTE));
var responseObj = (OCTE)serializer.Deserialize(soapBody.CreateReader());
```

The soap `Body` gets the `<ns:INCLUIRCONHECIMENTOFRETESAIDA>` with all information that I need. But when I deserialize it to `responseObj` I get all values as null.

Comment: Use `XDocument` and do `document.Descendant("OCTE")`? (or whatever the root name should be)

Comment: Descendant, not sure if i can find this member on XmlDocument class.

Comment: right, I confused it with `XDocument`. Can you use that class instead? Either way though, I'm sure there's a way to navigate the XML tree down to your body's value.

Comment: I can use, but then with Descendant i get an IENumerable instead a OCTE object

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing/extracting soap header and body from soap message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270314/removing-extracting-soap-header-and-body-from-soap-message)

Comment: Why not just deserialize with [`SoapFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkyt1t1f(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have enough details to fill in the namespaces and element names for you, but using [W3C's example SOAP response](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926101516/http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp), the following code and classes deserialize the object:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Desktop\CteWebservice.xml");
XNamespace soap = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope";
XNamespace m = "http://www.example.org/stock";
var responseXml = xdoc.Element(soap + "Envelope").Element(soap + "Body")
                      .Element(m + "GetStockPriceResponse");

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetStockPriceResponse));
var responseObj =
      (GetStockPriceResponse)serializer.Deserialize(responseXml.CreateReader());


[XmlRoot("GetStockPriceResponse", Namespace="http://www.example.org/stock")]
public class GetStockPriceResponse
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

You could do the same with your `OCTE` class.

```
[XmlRoot("INCLUIRCONHECIMENTOFRETESAIDA",Namespace="http://192.168.1.180:8085/")]
public class OCTE
{
    // with property mapping to CONHECIMENTOFRETE, etc.
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont get what is that response. The webservice doesnt return any response. I put some important part of my xml in the OP. thanks

Comment: @ggui the response corresponds to whatever class you have that mirrors INCLUIRCONHECIMENTOFRETESAIDA. I'm assuming this is OCTE, and have added code that shows what sort of attribute you'd need to put on that for the serializer to understand that that's what it is.

Comment: Yes, it is the OCTE Class. I get the information of the octe.xml file, then desiarize it to a OCTE object then send to the webservice as parameter. Ill try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: ok i get it. now i can get just the "important" part of the xml for my OCTE object. But when i deserialize it, i get all values null on the responseObj.

Comment: @ggui you probably need to include `XmlElementAttribute`s on your properties with the name and namespace (so that the serializer knows how to map the XML to your properties).

Comment: This Example was EXACTLY what I needed. My responses kept returning NULL so if anyone else is using a complex schema like mines (I had10 different namespaces to drill down through) be sure to utilize that .Element() feature. Create variables for all the namespaces and go from there.