# Parse Soap XML into Object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have the following SOAP XML

```
string soap = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ns='http://schemas.abudhabi.ae/sso/2010/11'>" +
   "<soapenv:Header/>" +
   "<soapenv:Body>" +
      "<ns:GetUserProfileResponse>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:userid>?</ns:userid>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:firstNameAr>?</ns:firstNameAr>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:firstNameEn>?</ns:firstNameEn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:middleNameAr>?</ns:middleNameAr>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:middleNameEn>?</ns:middleNameEn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:thirdNameAr>?</ns:thirdNameAr>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:thirdNameEn>?</ns:thirdNameEn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:fourthNameAr>?</ns:fourthNameAr>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:fourthNameEn>?</ns:fourthNameEn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:familyNameAr>?</ns:familyNameAr>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:familyNameEn>?</ns:familyNameEn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:authLevel>?</ns:authLevel>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:dateOfBirth>?</ns:dateOfBirth>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:gender>?</ns:gender>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:nationalityCode>?</ns:nationalityCode>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:idn>?</ns:idn>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:modifyTimestamp>?</ns:modifyTimestamp>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:prefComChannel>?</ns:prefComChannel>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:secretQuestionAnswer>?</ns:secretQuestionAnswer>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:secretQuestionId>?</ns:secretQuestionId>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:address>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:additionalAddressInfo>?</ns:additionalAddressInfo>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:city>?</ns:city>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:fax>?</ns:fax>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:residenceCountry>?</ns:residenceCountry>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:poBox>?</ns:poBox>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:stateOrEmirate>?</ns:stateOrEmirate>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:streetNameAndNumber>?</ns:streetNameAndNumber>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:zipCode>?</ns:zipCode>" +
         "</ns:address>" +
         "<!--Optional:-->" +
         "<ns:contact>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:email>?</ns:email>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:mobilePhoneNumber>?</ns:mobilePhoneNumber>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:website>?</ns:website>" +
            "<!--Optional:-->" +
            "<ns:workPhone>?</ns:workPhone>" +
         "</ns:contact>" +
      "</ns:GetUserProfileResponse>" +
   "</soapenv:Body>" +
"</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

I wanted it to Parse or Convert into following Class

```
public class UserProfile
        {
            public string FirstNameAR { get; set; }

            public string FirstNameEN { get; set; }

            public string MiddleNameAR { get; set; }

            public string MiddleNameEN { get; set; }

            public string ThirdNameAR { get; set; }
            public string ThirdNameEN { get; set; }


            public string FourthNameAR { get; set; }

            public string FourthNameEN { get; set; }

            public string FamilyNameAR { get; set; }

            public string FamilyNameEN { get; set; }

            public Boolean AuthLevelSpecified { get; set; }

            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public bool DateOfBirthSpecified { get; set; }


            public Boolean GenderTypeSpecified { get; set; }

            public string NationalityCode { get; set; }

            public string IDN { get; set; }

            public Boolean ModifyTimeStampSpecified { get; set; }
            public DateTime ModifyTimeStamp { get; set; }

            //  public PrefComChannelType PrefComChannelType { get; set; }
            public Boolean PrefComChannelTypeSpecified { get; set; }

            public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }

            public int SecretQuestionId { get; set; }

            public Boolean SecretQuestionSpecified { get; set; }
           }
```

and my code is :

```
var Value = XDocument.Parse(soap);

XNamespace ns = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
 var unwrappedResponse = Value.Descendants((XNamespace)"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" + "Body").First().FirstNode;

 XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserProfile));

 var responseObj = (UserProfile)oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(unwrappedResponse.CreateReader());
```

I am following this question [removing/extracting soap header and body from soap message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270314/removing-extracting-soap-header-and-body-from-soap-message)
But I am getting error.Is there any thing wrong with this Code.Please Help

Comment: What is the error ??

Comment: {"<GetUserProfileResponse xmlns='http://schemas.abudhabi.ae/sso/2010/11'> was not expected."}

Comment: I followed this but I am getting another error, Sequence contains no elements, can someone please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make your class name and property names match the names in the XML -- `"GetUserProfileResponse"` and, e.g., `"firstNameAr"`, keeping in mind that XML serialization is case-sensitive.  Alternatively, you need to use [attributes that control XML serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to map the XML element names to your class and property names.  You also need to tell the `XmlSerializer` that your class is serialized in the `"http://schemas.abudhabi.ae/sso/2010/11"` namespace.

The attributes that are useful to you are:

1. [`XmlRootAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - allows you to specify the name of the root element created from a given type, as well as its namespace.
2. [`XmlElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - allows you to specify the element names of members of a type being serialized.

Thus:

```
[XmlRoot("GetUserProfileResponse", Namespace = "http://schemas.abudhabi.ae/sso/2010/11")] // Serialized with root element name "GetUserProfileResponse" in namespace "http://schemas.abudhabi.ae/sso/2010/11".
public class UserProfile
{
    [XmlElement("firstNameAr")] // Serialized with element name "firstNameAr".
    public string FirstNameAR { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("firstNameEn")]
    public string FirstNameEN { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("middleNameAr")]
    public string MiddleNameAR { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("middleNameEn")]
    public string MiddleNameEN { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("thirdNameAr")]
    public string ThirdNameAR { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("thirdNameEn")]
    public string ThirdNameEN { get; set; }

    // Fix others similarly.
}
```

For more instructions, see [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You could also auto-generate your classes.  See [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml) for instructions.

Comment: I followed this but I am getting another error, Sequence contains no elements, can someone please help

Comment: @NKhan - sorry this isn't working for you.  If you need additional help, you should [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question, linking back to this one and providing a [mcve].  I can't guess the problem with just the exception message.