# Data Contract Name not being applied to response

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF endpoint which is sending an XML result. My Data contract is as per the follows:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "response")]
    public class GetAppointmentResult : response
```

However my output is showing the XML as `<GetAppointmentResult>`.

Is this the wrong way of doing this if the output is XML and therefore using an XML Serializer ?

Comment: The dataContract name has to match the tag tag name including lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: Judging from the datacontract you gave, there is no problem. You can provide the piece of code for converting data into xml format so that we can better help you solve the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in a demo fiddle, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcHZwS.  I think we will need to see a [mcve] to help you.  Are you sure you're not actually using `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: I am using XmlSerializer as i need data within the result to be a list of variables: `   <variable name="WSResult" value="success"/>` These have XML Attributes to show the data.

Comment: If you are using `XmlSerializer` you must use [`[XmlRoot("response")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute?view=netcore-3.1).  See [{"<user xmlns=''> was not expected.} Deserializing Twitter XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557145/3744182), [Parse Soap XML into Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471240/3744182) and [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization).